# 2.8 Cycle Render Mode ignore Local view mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

When I try to preview an Object in Local View with Cycles, all my objects are rendered together. It seems that Cycles ignores Local View.
Is it a bug or is there another method/shortcut for it?[image]

Comment: Yes, but when I want do smth on the shader, I dont want to see the whole scene, but only one object

Comment: You are right, was working in 2.79 @3Dbob. Might worth it reporting that as bug...

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T61797). As [brecht as confirmed](https://developer.blender.org/T61797#743526):

> It will be fixed for the next release.

Comment: lol confirmed back in February, I thought they made it like that intentionally.
Edit: i just saw it is high priority now

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Make a collection called something like Local View, and move objects there temporarily while working on them with cycles. This is what I do when working on big assemblies.